# Rails Cannot create Plugin Tables in Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, development-environment, redmine-plugins

Long story short, Running a `rake` command is not creating database tables for my Redmine plugin while the RAILS_ENV is set to development. Using the tutorial I saw [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial)

It does say set the environment to production. However I prefer development, if I'm going to be testing the plugin and making sure it works. The `rails server -e development` command gives me detailed logging in the console while production only lets me know when an error has occurred. Is there anyway to get rails to create my table in development?

Comment: and in your database.yml you do have development database parameters configured ?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: And you did try rake redmine:plugins:migrate ?

Comment: That is also correct.